# Targeting Elements on Click

Tags: javascript, html, events

I found a small "To Do List" exercise in which the user clicks on a list item and a JS function changes the background of what was clicked to a different color, using an e.target.tagName.

Now I understand there are easier ways to do this but I wanted to experiment with passing an event that a function "looks for" and then activates a particular feature but I'm a little stuck.

In my example, instead of a list, the function looks for a P element.  I can get the following to work if I search for e.target.tagName == "P", however I wanted to try looking by the ID.  When I change the function to read e.target.Id === "text" however, it does not work.  What am I missing?

Code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>

<div id="list2">
<p id="text">Text</p>
<p id="text">Text</p>
<p id="text">Text</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var list = document.querySelector("ul");

list.onclick = function(e)
{
if(e.target.tagName === "LI")
{
    e.target.classList.toggle("done");
}
};


var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");

list2.onclick = function(e)
{
if(e.target.Id === "text")
{
    e.target.classList.toggle("done");
}
};
```

Comment: Try with `e.target.id`, id in lowecase,

Comment: you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. id should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main issues:

**1)** You cannot have elements with the same id. Ids are unique to elements, and CANNOT be repeated. Classes on the other hand, you can have multiple of.

**2)** Addressing your main question, `id` should be in lowercase, rather than uppercase. So changing your code to : `e.target.id` does the trick.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `e.target.Id`. It should `id`(lower case) since `javascript` is a case-sensitive language.

```js
var list = document.querySelector("ul");

list.onclick = function(e)
{
if(e.target.tagName === "LI")
{
    e.target.classList.toggle("done");
}
};


var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");

list2.onclick = function(e)
{
if(e.target.id === "text")
{
    e.target.classList.toggle("done");
}
};
```

```css
.done{
  background-color:greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>

<div id="list2">
<p id="text">Text</p>
<p id="text">Text</p>
<p id="text">Text</p>
</div>
```